# Adding an object to a parent array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm passing a 'todo' object from a child component to its parent, which triggers a function `addTodo` on the parent component.

This function then needs to add the event data to an array of objects. The problem is that the event data is nested within another object. (please see the console log screenshot).

https://i.ibb.co/pZmHjBg/Screenshot-2019-11-02-at-15-08-42.png

My question is, how should I be piping this data so it gets passed into my `addToDo` function correctly? Or is it a case of unwrapping the event data once it reaches the `addToDo` function?

Thanks in advance.

```
//Child Component

    sendForm () {
      const title = this.titleText
      const project = this.projectText
      this.$emit('add-todo', {
        title: title,
        project: project,
        done: false
      })
      this.newTodoText = ''
      this.isCreating = false
    }
```

//Parent component

```
addTodo (toDo) {
  console.log(toDo)
  this.todos.push({
    toDo
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.todos))
}


  data () {
    return {
      todos: [{
        title: 'Todo A',
        project: 'Project A',
        done: false
      }, {
        title: 'Todo B',
        project: 'Project B',
        done: true
      }, {
        title: 'Todo C',
        project: 'Project C',
        done: false
      }, {
        title: 'Todo D',
        project: 'Project D',
        done: false
      }]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

```
addTodo (toDo) {
  this.todos.push(toDo)
}
```

Because the data you pass from the child component itself is an Object, so you don't need to use the `{}` symbol anymore.

Comment: Great spot! Thanks very much.

Comment: @JoeCarre check this out - [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and you'll know what your problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am seeing everything correctly, the problem is that the emit is firing on the child node and not being caught in the parent. Try this

```
this.$parent.$emit('add-todo', {
        title: title,
        project: project,
        done: false
      })
```

In this yours was `this.$emit`, I am proposing `this.$parent.$emit`

Comment: It is firing the parent function correctly, but thank you anyway!